# React doesn't seem to recognize the '=' symbol in my .js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm facing an issue while trying to get a react app to work.
When compiling using babel, it seems that the '=' symbol in my .js file isn't recognized...And it returns me "Uncaught Error: Module build failed: SyntaxError". I don't know how to solve this issue and it's really beginning to get on my nerves :) .
Here's my webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
entry: ['babel-polyfill', './lib/main.js'],
output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname)
},
devtool: 'source-map',
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
            }
        }
    ]
}
};
```

Here's the beginning of my main.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import _ from 'lodash';


const createArray = (size) => Array.from({ length: size }, (_, i) => i);

class Cell extends React.Component {
backgroundColor = () => {
```

And my index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Memory Game</title>
  <!-- certainly some style rules here -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="react"> Loading...</div>
  <script src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance, and please, keep in mind that I'm a beginner :)
Have a nice evening!

Comment: What is the **exact** error message you get and what line causes it?

Comment: Do you have babel-preset-react installed?

Comment: Your main.js seems incomplete. Probably a copy and paste error, but can you double check to see if it you close the class properly?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, it is on the line 9 of the main.js file and the error message is "Uncaught Error: Module build failed: SyntaxError: C:/Users/Florian/tp4ter/lib/main.js: Unexpected token (9:18)"

Comment: @jmargolisvt Yes I do :)

Comment: @Amir I just posted a little part of my main.js because the error is triggered in the very beginning: at line 9 the '=' is listed as unexpected token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
                presets: ['react', 'es2015'],
                plugins: ['react-html-attrs', 'transform-class-properties', 'transform-decorators-legacy']
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

With the appropriate modules:

```
"babel-plugin-react-html-attrs"
"babel-plugin-transform-class-properties"
"babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy"
"babel-preset-es2015"
"babel-preset-react"
```